# php with multiple list item box

Tags: php

Its first time I am using select box for multiple values. my html code is

```
<select name="depend_on" size="3" multiple="multiple" class="text_field_detail" id="depend_on"  style="width:250px;"><? get_service_dependent_list($x); ?></select>
```

I am requesting all set of selected values. I used php script as

```
    $depend_on = array();
    $depend_on[] = $_REQUEST["depend_on"];
```

$depent_on echo single last selected value. How can I retrieve all selected values from multiple select box ?

Comment: How can I retrieve all selected values from multiple select box.

Comment: Pretty sure your input name has to be an array. `name="depend_on[]"`. I don't really understand why you're making a new array and appending the `_request` to it.

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of your select:

```
<select name="depend_on[]" ... ></select>
```

The same principle as when you name each of the group of checkboxes. Square brackets act like an array collecting multiple values.

Comment: Got my error... Thanks..

Comment: @RahulSingh : why not accept one answer if its solved your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Add brackets in your HTML name:

```
<select name="depend_on[]" size="3" multiple="multiple" class="text_field_detail" id="depend_on"  style="width:250px;"><? get_service_dependent_list($x); ?></select>
```

In your PHP the "depend_on" variable will now be an array. You don't want to try to set an element of it:

```
$depend_on = $_POST['depend_on'];
```